# Can ssh via tunnel from root, can't from user account

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

I have two users on `desktop` - `root` and `user`. I have a `bastion` and a `protected` host. When run `ssh protected` as `root` on `desktop`, I connect fine. When I run `ssh protected` as `user` on `desktop`, I get no output - just a blank line, like it's waiting for something. However, `user` *can* log in directly to the `bastion` host and from there to the `protected` host.

Both `root` and `user` have the same contents in their `.ssh` directories (`#cp -r ~/.ssh /home/user; chown -R user:user /home/user/.ssh`).

The `bastion` host appears to be forwarding properly - running `$(which sshd) -Ddp 10222` (per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/9583) shows the same `debug1: channel 0: connected to protected port 22` line on both.

Running the same on `protected` shows the same output until:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
```

The second line does *not* display when connecting from `user` on `desktop`.

`ssh -vvv protected` as `user` on `desktop` shows:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018                                                                                                                       
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config                                                                                                     
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *                                                                                                
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for protected                                                                                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config                                                                                                          
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh bastion -W protected:22                                                                                                
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_protected type 0                                                                                                         
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_protected-cert type -1                                                                                                   
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9                                                                                                                
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \033[3g
\033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H     \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H    \033H
SSH-2.0-Op
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: enSSH_7.9


debug1: ssh_exchange_identification:
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 6,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com                                                       
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
```

As `root` on `desktop` everything is the same up until the first `ssh_exchange_identification` line.

My ssh config is:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 60
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host           bastion
HostName       bastion.host
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_protected
User           user

Host          protected
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_protected
Hostname       protected
User           user
ProxyCommand   ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

I have also tried https://askubuntu.com/a/976226/427339, but I believe this doesn't apply for two reasons - 1. emptying my `~/.config/fish/fish.config` made no difference, and 2. I can log in to the same `user` on `protected` *from* `root` on `desktop`.

All three systems are running Arch Linux. `protected` and `desktop` are both using the `fish` shell.

Edit:

`user`@`bastion`'s `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 60

Host protected
User user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_protected
```

This, as mentioned above, works fine to log into protected. `/etc/hosts` has an entry for `protected` pointing to the net-local IP - 10.x.x.x.

Edit 2:

My issue appears very similar to these:

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.security.ssh/e1nObaX5ZWg/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.security.ssh/_HDV0JXXQA8/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.security.ssh/tDgwEDJKGuE/discussion

I have not yet tried the MTU workaround, and am not familiar enough with protocol analyzers to have one set up and handy right now.

Edit 3:

Adding `-v` to the `ProxyCommand` (is now `ProxyCommand ssh -v bastion -W %h:%p`), full output of `user@desktop$ ssh protected`:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for bastion
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bastion [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_protected type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_protected-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to bastion:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none                                                             
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none                                                             
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY                                                                                                                       
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HfDmNOGgLrPLMsnCbyZuEuJapj+T6wrSTTiFSd+37ag                                                                 
debug1: Host 'bastion' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.                                                                                           
debug1: Found key in /home/users/.ssh/known_hosts:3                                                                                                           
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_protected RSA SHA256:iH5F4stK+j+2/qkGJlL5D6TOEHNiwbR4jCzckI7IHaE explicit agent                                   
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_protected RSA SHA256:iH5F4stK+j+2/qkGJlL5D6TOEHNiwbR4jCzckI7IHaE explicit agent                                
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_protected RSA SHA256:iH5F4stK+j+2/qkGJlL5D6TOEHNiwbR4jCzckI7IHaE explicit agent                                 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bastion ([x.x.x.x]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd protected:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
--- very long delay; from `root` everything is the same till here, but the next line is `Last login: ...`, etc - a successful connection ---
debug1: channel 0: FORCE input drain
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for protected port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 1.
```

Comment: Just in case, to verify the obvious: The permissions on both `.ssh` and their contents are the same (You used `cp -r`, not `cp -a`)? You double-checked that the owner change worked correctly?

Comment: @dirkt Yep, I entered the commands as pasted, except on two lines instead of with a `;`. I would have gotten a different error had the directory had the wrong permissions - I don't recall it, but I've seen it before. Visual inspection just now confirms - the files are owned by `user:user`, `config` and `id_protected` are `0600` and `id_protected.pub` and `known_hosts` are `0644`. The `/home/user/.ssh` directory is `700` and also owned by `user:user`.

Comment: probably need a `ForwardAgent  yes` in each `Host` section at least, plus I use `nc` as the proxy.

Comment: @strobelight tried that - neither made any difference, separate or together. `root`@`desktop` can still log in via `bastion`, `user`@`desktop` still cannot. I typically dislike using `nc` as the proxy as it tends to leave running `nc` processes on `bastion`. I'll add `user`@`bastion`'s `.ssh/config` to the post - it's set up so it can log in direct, so I wouldn't need agent forwarding (either way didn't make a difference though).

Comment: is the private key the same for both root and user? they don't have to be, but the corresponding public key of each must be in the .ssh/authorized_keys files.

Comment: your user ssh config isn't using the bastion host, so duplicate the bastion entry and use it in the protected entry since to get to protected you have to go through the bastion whether or not from root or user.

Comment: @strobelight maybe I should rename `user` - the second ssh config is _on `bastion`_, not on `desktop`. The private key _is_ the same for both `root`@`desktop` and `user`@`desktop` - as the whole directory is copied. However - the private key for `user`@`bastion` is different. Nevertheless - `user`@`bastion` _can_ log in, `root`@`desktop` _can_ log in, and `user`@`desktop` _cannot_ - with the same private key and config as `root`@`desktop`.

Comment: Have you tried to add -v option to ssh in ProxyCommand and check its output?

Comment: @Tomek no, I hadn't :). Added output to the question. Doesn't appear to shed any additional light sadly.

Comment: Actually it does. The problem is with the proxy connection to bastion. Can you login as user on bastion using ssh from user on desktop? If yes, I would start looking into your shell init files if they have anything relying on SSH_* environment variables. Looking into pam and sshd configuration hunting for any restrictions may also be worthwhile.

Comment: @Tomek I mention in block 12 (starting with "I have also tried...") that I've tried that - further, it is getting through `bastion` when connecting through `bastion` from `root`@`desktop`. I mentioned in the 5th sentence of my first paragraph that I can also login from `user`@`bastion` to `protected`. Checking the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for `user`@`bastion` again reveals nothing before the `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` line.

Answer (score 0):

Since your protected host is behind a bastion host, you still need to go through the bastion host in order to reach it whether from a *root* user or normal *user* account.

Simply duplicate the root ssh config to the user ssh config and you should be good to go, but add a `ForwardAgent   yes` in each `Host` section for both the root user and your normal user on your desktop.

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 60
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host           bastion
HostName       bastion.host
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_protected
User           user
ForwardAgent   yes

Host          protected
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_protected
Hostname       protected
User           user
ForwardAgent   yes
ProxyCommand   ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

The `sshd_config` file on the bastion as well as the protected host, usually in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, will need to have `AllowAgentForwarding  yes` which is usually the default but worth checking. If you do have to change, then restart sshd after saving.

Hopefully the private keys are the same between root and normal user, but if not, ensure the corresponding public keys are in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the bastion host as well as the protected host. In other words, the bastion users' `.ssh/authorized_keys` file has an entry (single line, 2 or 3 space-separated fields) containing the public keys of the corresponding private ones used from your desktop and so does the protected host.

If you don't have the public keys any longer, you can get them via this command:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /path/to/private_key
```

Comment: That is exactly what I stated I did in my question in the second paragraph.

Comment: My understanding is you have two account on *desktop*, *root* and *user* and you're trying to go directly to the protected host *user* account from your desktop whether logged in as *root* or as *user*.

`
sudo -i
sum .ssh/config
sum ~user/.ssh/config
# above two numbers should match

sum .ssh/id_protected
sum ~user/.ssh/id_protected
# above two numbers should match
`

an ssh config on the bastion is only useful if actually logging into the bastion first.

Comment: 1) I have two accounts on `desktop`, correct. 2) I am trying to go directly to `protected` from `desktop` whether logged in as `user` or `root`, correct. 3) `sudo -i sum /root/.ssh/config ~user/.ssh/config` are both the same, correct. 4) `sudo -i sum /root/.ssh/id_protected ~user/.ssh/id_protected` are both the same, correct. This was demonstrated however in paragraph 2 of my question, however, I have repeated these steps for you and verified that I can still log in from `root`@`desktop` and cannot from `user`@`desktop`. I will leave the bastion config for now, as it might help someone else.

Comment: `AllowAgentFowarding` is at the default `yes` on both `protected` and `bastion` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
I have shown 3 times now that the private keys are the same between `root` and `user` @ `desktop`. I have _again_ put `ForwardAgent yes` in both entries of `/root/.ssh/config` and then copied/chowned `/root/.ssh` to `/home/user/.ssh` and the `protected` host still shows the same result - `root`@`desktop` logs in fine, `user`@`desktop` stops at `debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]`. I am frustrated that you have now asked me to take the same steps 2 and 3 times respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem shelling from `laptop` (not mentioned in question - I also have `pi` and several other computers not relevant to the issue) to `desktop` - which is set up very similarly to `protected`. The symptom:

```
user@laptop$ ssh desktop "echo foo" | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3367 0d1b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020  .[3g..H    .H
00000010: 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820   .H    .H    .H
00000020: 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b     .H    .H    . 
00000030: 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020  H    .H    .H
00000040: 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820   .H    .H    .H
00000050: 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b     .H    .H    .
00000060: 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020  H    .H    .H
00000070: 201b 4820 2020 201b 4820 2020 0d66 6f6f   .H    .H   .foo
00000080: 0a
```

This was easily fixed by changing the line `tabs -4` to `status --is-interactive; and tabs -4` in `/home/user/.config/fish/config.fish` on `desktop`. This change I have already made some time ago on `protected`.

However - changing the `/home/user/.config/fish/config.fish` on *`desktop`* appears to have fixed the login from `user`@`desktop` to `user`@`protected`. I am posting this as an answer as I feel the resolution is somewhat novel - https://askubuntu.com/a/976226/427339 which I linked in the question states that I need to check for commands producing output *on `protected`*, and I resolved this by changing a command which produces output *on `desktop`*.

That said, I would love to mark as accepted an answer which explains how and why my shell configuration on the local machine interfered with the ssh pipe, but *not* direct ssh connections.

Until then, I have come to the tentative conclusion that `tabs` is a risky program, and should be treated with the utmost of caution if placing it in a shell startup file.